# Error registering a Tomcat 7 server in Netbeans 7 (Catalina Home folder is not valid)

Tags: tomcat, netbeans

I'm running Netbeans 7.0.1 on Linux Mint DE.  Netbeans was installed through the distro's repositories.  I've now installed the package tomcat7-user so I can create a user instance of Tomcat which I can start or stop as required.  When I start this instance (using bin/startup.sh) the script reports:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/david/tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/david/tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started
```

So, in Netbeans, I go to Tools -> Servers, click Add Server, select Apache Tomcat, click next and in the Server Location (Catalina Home) field I put `/usr/share/tomcat7`.  But Netbeans reports:

> The specified Server Location (Catalina Home) folder is not valid.

I thought perhaps it's a permissions issue so I (temporarily) chmoded everything in /usr/share/tomcat7 (including that folder itself) to 0777 but still that error message appears.  So my next thought is maybe there's something missing, so I symlinked all of the folders in Catalina base into Catalina home, but still no luck.

Now it would be very helpful if Netbeans actually told you not just that a problem exists, but what the problem actually is, too.  I'm quite close to going through the Netbeans source code to find out what it actually wants, but if anyone could shed some light on this for me that would save me an awful lot of fuss!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I downloaded the Netbeans source code this weekend and found out the hard way.

For some reason, Netbeans thinks I have an old version of Tomcat, so it's looking for the `${CATALINA_HOME}/common/lib` folder.  The following terminal commands fixed the problem:

```
cd /usr/share/tomcat7
sudo mkdir common
sudo ln -s lib common/lib
```

Answer (score 2):

I created the `${CATALINA_HOME}/common/lib` folder and now it works for me too.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe better:

```
cd /usr/share/tomcat7
sudo mkdir common
sudo ln -sf /usr/share/tomcat7/lib /usr/share/tomcat7/common/lib
```

Comment: Out of interest, why?  The -f option isn't needed as there are not going to be any existing files as the directory has just been created.  So I'm assuming you're suggesting that it's better to use absolute rather than relative paths.  If so, could you explain why this would be better?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The following fixed Apache TomCat Server (apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M4) registration problem in NetBeans-8.0.2 on openSuSE 13.1 x86_64 linux:

As root user,

1. `# cd /opt`
2. `# ln -s apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M4 tomcat`
3. `# ln -sf /opt/tomcat/lib /opt/tomcat/common/lib`

Then add server on NetBeans as per standard procedure.

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete all tomcats installations,
2. If you have the netbeans installer with tomcat installation, run again, in customized button, clicked and check tomcat only
3. Now, you can open netbeans and add a new tomcat server

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but as is stated in the question, Netbeans was installed as a package through the Linux Mint DE repositories, not from a standalone installer with a bundled Tomcat server, and also at the time I wanted to make use of the Tomcat user instances feature provided by the tomcat7-user package.  I did not want to install a single Tomcat server instance.