# netbeans 7.1.3 tomcat server location not valid

Tags: tomcat, netbeans

I am using netbenas 7.1.3.

When I try to add the tomcat server to netbeans it says  "The specified server location(Catalina Home) folder is not valid".

I have the CATALINA_HOME and JAVA_HOME class paths working as I can get the tomcat server running fine on its own.

I'm using windows 8 x64. The location tomcat is C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.0-RC1.

Any help with this would be great. I have tried several approaches. This includes creating a user with administrative privileges in tomcat its self.[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371059/error-registering-a-tomcat-7-server-in-netbeans-7-catalina-home-folder-is-not-v

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution.

Delete the CATALINA_HOME and JAVA_HOME class paths and

use tomcat version 7 not version 8

Comment: Is this the only solution.   Suppose I need to use tomcat version 8?

Comment: And also what if need to use eclipse(Springsource) also. In that case i need these classpaths. Any other solution? what is the cause of the above issue??

Answer (score 1):

Try installing [the latest version](https://netbeans.org/downloads/) of Netbeans.

If you're running an older version of Netbeans, it may not support the latest versions of Tomcat.