# The specified Server Location (Catalina Home) folder is not valid. Tomcat 9 with Netbeans 8.1

Tags: macos, tomcat, netbeans

I cant add tomcat server in netbeans. 
I'm using:

- Mac OS El Capitan
- Tomcat 9.0.0.M6
- Netbeans 8.1

I tried with this [accepted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371059/error-registering-a-tomcat-7-server-in-netbeans-7-catalina-home-folder-is-not-v) but didn't help either

[image: netbeans]

[image: finder]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following command which I just used to setup my Tomcat 9.0.0.M9 with Netbeans 8.1 under osx

I renamed the download file `'apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M9'` as `'tomcat-9.0'` and put it under `/Applications`. So the path is `/Applications/tomcat-9.0`. Then the commands should be:

```
cd /Applications

sudo mkdir tomcat-9.0/common

ln -sf /Applications/tomcat-9.0/lib /Applications/tomcat-9.0/common/lib
```

Then you choose `/Applications/tomcat-9.0` as Catalina home in your Netbeans and it should work.