# mac, trying to install tomcat server on netbeans, keep getting error "The specified Server Location (Catalina Home) folder is not valid."

Tags: tomcat, netbeans, server

I'm trying to install Tomcat server on NetBeans. I have downloaded the Tomcat files and placed it in.

[image: demo]

But I am keeping getting error: "The specified Server Location (Catalina Home) folder is not valid."

[image: error]

Why is this happening, and how to solve it?

Comment: Try these two solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371059/error-registering-a-tomcat-7-server-in-netbeans-7-catalina-home-folder-is-not-v   and  http://razius.com/articles/installing-and-adding-an-external-tomcat-server-in-netbeans/

Comment: Do you have permission to create a directory within the /Library directory?  I know that when you install software in that directory you need administrator permission to do so.

Comment: @ClaudioCorsi yes i do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use Tomcat 8.x and try again. IMHO NetBeans currently does not support Tomcat 9, which is still under development and no production release is available.

Answer (score 4):

I am running NetBeans 8.2 on my Mac. I have Tomcat 9.0.8 installed via homebrew. After extensive Googling I was unable to find a solution. It took me a few hours to solve this.

```
cd /usr/local/opt/tomcat/libexec/bin
ln -s catalina.sh catalina
```

Set up your server as follows:

[image: Server dialog screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans 8.2 supports Tomcat 9.

If you're using Netbeans 8.1, upgrade it to Netbeans 8.2