# Ubuntu 16.04 adding Tomcat9 in Netbeans 8.2 - Error:The specified Server Location (Catalina Home) folder is not valid

Tags: tomcat, netbeans

I've installed Tomcat 9 and Netbeans 8.2 in Ubuntu 16.04. I've tried to add Tomcat in Netbeans as a server but says: **The specified Server Location (Catalina Home) folder is not valid**.

I've looking for the solution but nothing worked.

I've installed tomcat in folder: /opt/tomcat.

I've tried to create symbolic links such as:

sudo ln -s /opt/tomcat/ /usr/share/tomcat/conf
sudo ln -sf /opt/tomcat/lib /opt/tomcat/common/lib

But as I said nothing worked.

Could you help me please?

Thanks,
Roberto

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371059/error-registering-a-tomcat-7-server-in-netbeans-7-catalina-home-folder-is-not-v hope  it may help you.

Comment: I've tried it but it didn't work. Any other suggestions please?

Answer (score 2):

hi roberto i dont know if you solve this problem but for another people i solved this problem in ubuntu 18.04 with 
chmod -R 777 apache-tomcat-9.0.14/
working perfectly
perfectly,
Sorry for my english not is my primary language

Comment: I am also having similar problem, you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60983938/create-symbolic-link-for-access-file-using-tomcat-9

 i can access any file if file is exist inside ../tomcat/webapps/ROOT, but i am creating symbolic link inside ROOT, trying to access localhost:8080/folder/abc.pdf, while using tomcat7 is working fine

Answer (score 0):

In my Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS I have installed Tomcat from this link [Tomcat installation guide](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-tomcat-9-on-ubuntu-20-04/) in /opt/tomcat folder .
When I installed Netbeans I was facing the similar issue so I just change the permission of /opt/tomcat/ with **sudo chmod -R 777 /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat/** command and it worked for me.