# create symbolic link for access file using tomcat 9 - not working

Tags: tomcat9

I am migrating tomcat 7 to tomcat 9.0.33, below are the symbolic link access config for tomcat 7 but the link is not working on tomcat, can anyone pls suggest how to fix this

> `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
>   <Context path="/" docBase="/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.63/webapps/ROOT" allowLinking="true" deployXML="false">`

Comment: what is the os?

Comment: centos 7, in my webapp/ROOT i have linked few folder which i need to access using localhost/foldername/abc.png,  In tomcat 7 using above config is working well

Comment: I have put above  ROOX.xml file inside /usr/local/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml

Answer (score 1):

in tomcat 9 & 8
need to add into tomcat/conf/context.xml

> `<Context>
>       <Resources allowLinking="true" />
>        ....`

[got help from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22240776/symlinking-tomcat-8-directory-resources)

Comment: This, and lots of other useful information is in the migration guide:
http://tomcat.apache.org/migration-8.html
http://tomcat.apache.org/migration-9.html